# Python scatter plot colorbar with axes objects

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to produce a simple scatter plot from a table, and I want to color-code the points in the plot based on one of the columns in the table itself.
I managed to do it so far, by using

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax.scatter(sub_ZH_match[:,9], sub_ZH_match[:,10], c=sub_ZH_match[:,2], s=60, marker=mod_marker, edgecolors='black', cmap=cm.jet_r, label='matches')
```

where, obviously

```
sub_ZH_match[:,9] -> x values
sub_ZH_match[:,10] -> y values
sub_ZH_match[:,2] -> values for the color coding.
```

but I don't get how to actually show the colorbar on the side of the plot.

It works when using this syntax

```
plt.scatter(sub_ZH_match[:,9], sub_ZH_match[:,10], c=sub_ZH_match[:,2], s=60, marker=mod_marker, edgecolors='black', cmap=cm.jet_r, label='matches')
clb = plt.colorbar()
clb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=18)
clb.set_label(r'$\nu$', fontsize=20)
```

but I wanted to understand how to do it when sticking to the syntax with the axes objects.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

scatter = ax.scatter(sub_ZH_match[:,9], sub_ZH_match[:,10], c=sub_ZH_match[:,2], s=60, marker=mod_marker, edgecolors='black', cmap=cm.jet_r, label='matches')
colorbar = fig.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax)
```